# Show summary if php loop?

Tags: php

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
  /* For Loop for all sheets */
  for($i=0;$i<$totalSheet;$i++) {

    $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);

    foreach ($Reader as $Row) {

  //variables here

  $query = "INSERT INTO schools (
 //code here
 )";
           if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
          echo "<br> New record created successfully <br>";
        } else {
          echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
        }
     }
  }
```

How do I turn this:

```
  if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
          echo "<br> New record created successfully <br>";
```

into a code that will show something like:

XX inputted successfully
{list of schools with ID listed here}
XX not inpputed due to errors
{list of schools not inputted}

Would like to see a simple summary of the entire loop rather than seeing a repeated result of each loop that occurred.

Comment: for a start you should not run insert in a loop. concatenate your values in the loop and then insert once only

Comment: @rtfm no idea how to "concatenate" the values in the loop.  I had somebody else write the php script.  I just need help modifying it.  The purpose of the script is to read data from an .xls file and insert the data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Collect all the information you want in variables, and print them at the end.

```
$success = $fail = "";
$success_count = $fail_count = 0;

for($i=0;$i<$totalSheet;$i++) {

    $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);

    foreach ($Reader as $Row) {

        //variables here

        $query = "INSERT INTO schools (
            //code here
            )";
        if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
            $success .= "<li>" . $Row['school_name'] . "</li>";
            $success_count++;
        } else {
            $fail .= "<li>" . $Row['school_name'] . "</li>";
            $fail_count++;
        }
    }
}

echo $success_count . " inputted successfully:<br><ul>" . $success . "</ul>";
echo $fail_count . " not inputted due to errors:<br><ul>" . $fail . "</ul>";
```

Replace `$Row['school_name']` with whatever the correct variable is for the school name in your data.

Comment: Got Notice messages saying `$fail` and `$fail_count` are undefined variables.  How do you print or echo the  .$Row['variable here']  if the variable had an isset in the loop?  Example:  in the foreach loop when the variables were being declared, school name was declared as this:  $name = isset($Row[1]) ? $Row[1] : '';

Comment: fixed the undefined variables problem.  Still get a "Undefined Index" notice for the variable that I put for $Row.  I want to display the school name and then underneath the school name, if there was an error, the sql error message.  The code I used (which apparently doesn't work is: $fail .= "<li>" . $Row['name'] . "<br>" . $mysqli->error . "</li>";

Comment: I just had to guess what the contents of `$Row` are, you'll need to change that to match where the name really is.

Comment: Solved it with the help of a friend of mine: Replaced $Row['name'] with $name.

Comment: Where does that variable come from? Doesn't it need to be something different for each row?

Comment: No, because I am only displaying data from one variable.  $name represents one field in the database where there are lots of rows of data.  If you see my code, $name is already defined.

Comment: I don't see `$name` anywhere in the code you posted. If `$name` is a field in the database, shouldn't it come from `$Row`? It needs to be different for each school you're inserting, right?

Comment: oh, my mistake.....the part of the code that defined $name is not posted in my question....sorry about that.  but yes it is posted within the foreach loop where you can see "//variables here".  The exact code is: $name = isset($Row[1]) ? $Row[1] : '';  Each school NAME is inserted into the column/field, $name, which is the data I want to be displayed.  If an error occurs which each school submission, I want to know the NAME of the school that has the error.